# Maximal pair-wise intersection between arcs on a discrete circle

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Consider a discrete circle made of $N$ points: $\mathcal{C}=\left\{ {0,1,...,N - 1} \right\}$. An $n$-arc $\mathcal{A}$ on the circle is formed by choosing a point $c \in \mathcal{C}$, such that $\mathcal{A} = \left\{ {c,c + 1,...,c + n - 1} \right\} {\rm mod} \hspace{2pt} N$. Now assume $M$ independent $n$-arcs, each formed by choosing a point at random out of $\mathcal{C}$: $\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,...,\mathcal{A}_M$. I want to find the probability that the intersection size of each arc pair is at most $s$, that is, what is $\Pr \left( {{{\max }_{i,j}}\left| {{\mathcal{A}_i} \cap {\mathcal{A}_j}} \right| \le s} \right)$.

If $M=2$, then the problem is simple. The first arc can be placed on any of the $N$ points. The number of ways to get the second arc overlapping on $t$ points of the first arc is $N-2n+1$ if $t=0$, $2$ if $1 \le t < n$ and $1$ if $t=n$. This means that the desired probability for $M=2$ is obtained by summing over the number of ways to obtain at most $s$ overlapping points, multiplying this number by $N$ (the number of possible points for the first arc), and normalizing by $N^2$. However, when $M \ge 3$ I do not find an efficient way to do this counting.

EDIT:

The constraint of maximal intersection $s$ means that the starting points of any two arcs should be at least $n-s$ points apart, but no more than $N-(n-s)$ points apart. In addition, due to symmetry we can assume that the starting points $c_1,c_2,...,c_m$ are ordered, i.e. $c_1 \le c_2 ... \le c_M$ where we need to multiply the number of arcs under this ordering by $M!$. Therefore, my question boils down to counting the number of points in the set

$$T = \left\{ {{c_1},{c_2},...,{c_M}:n - s \le {c_j} - {c_i} \le N - \left( {n - s} \right),1 \le i<j \le M} \right\}$$